# Uglify.JS minifies filename instead of file contents

Tags: javascript, gulp, gruntjs, minify, uglifyjs

I'm using uglifyjs to minify js files, but when I run the tool it minifies the file name I passed and not the content.

```
var resultugly = UglifyJS.minify(['app_client/app.js']);
console.log(resultugly.code);
```

and the log result is: app_client,app.js; not the file content

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: From the documentation it looks like `minify()` doesn't read from the filesystem, you pass it the actual code's text to have it minified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, what happens is that I need to use the function readFileSync from the 'fs' module before to import the file, for example:

```
var appClientFiles = [
  fs.readFileSync('app_client/app.js', "utf8")
];
```

then just pass the vector with the or files as a parameter of the uglify minify function as below:

```
var resultugly = UglifyJS.minify(appClientFiles);
```

I hope I can help someone